# How to use Future<Bool> function result in if condition without using async function

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, asynchronous, future

I'm new in Flutter, I have this function to check if the userType is premium or not.
The Function is return Future type and I want to use the result in If statement to show and hide some widgets..

```
Future<bool> isUserPremium() async {
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final User user = _auth.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      final DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user.uid)
          .get();
      final bool isPremium = snapshot['userType'] == 'UserType.premium';

      return isPremium;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

And I want to use the result as condition in if statement here..

```
         child: Stack(
            children: [
              ClipOval(
                child: Material(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                    placeholder: 'assets/images/gif_loading.gif',
                    image: widget.imageUrl,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    width: 200,
                    height: 200,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
             // The problem here I want to use it without async or without await
             // What can I do ?
              if (await profilProvider.isUserPremium())
              Positioned(
                top: 10,
                right: 15,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.star,
                  size: 40,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

I tried "didChangeDependencies" function but it doesn't work.

```
  var _isPremium = false;
  var _isInit = true;
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    if (_isInit) {
      _isPremium = false;
      final profilProivder = Provider.of<Profil>(context, listen: false);
      _isPremium = await profilProivder.isUserPremium();
    }
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _isInit = false;
  }
```

Comment: Have you considered a then() extension function? You can use it in initState.  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/then.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `await` in a builder. Instead you should [use a `FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), which handles the asynchronous nature of the `Future`.

```
FutureBuilder<String>(  
  future: isUserPremium(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) return Text("ERROR: ${snapshot.error}");
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();

    var data = snapshot.data!;

    if (data == true) {
      return Positioned(
        top: 10,
        right: 15,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.star,
          size: 40,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      );
    }
    return null;
  },
```